# Getting error when running mvc web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC technology. I got an error when I am running my MVC app. I have attached my code and error image. Please resolve my problem.

[image]

I have added a controller named `Default1Controller.cs` and code of this controller is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you modify your RouteConfig for Default1Controller? By default it runs HomeController and Index action. If you change your controller name you must modify RouteConfig in App_start

Comment: how to restore this routeconfig?

Comment: this is my routeconfig
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }

Comment: Change your controller name to HomeControler instead Default1Controler and everything will be fine

Comment: no this is not working..

Comment: `public class HomeController : Controller{}`

Comment: thank you....i can understand now...what was the error...

Answer (score 1):

Just change this in your `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

To this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default1", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Because by default it runs `HomeController`.

But if you don't want to change the `RouteConfig` you could rename your controller to `HomeController` or type this in your address bar:

```
http://localhost:55416/default1
```

Comment: line 'defaults:' describes de default controller and action

Comment: @Marcin...Yes. And The OP wants the `Default1` controller to be as a default controller.

Comment: Where he said that? ;) Just want to describe the basics it's doesn't matter if it's Default1 or homeController. Right now anshul gupta will be know what to do and where

Comment: @anshulgupta...Check my updated answer. the `controller="Home"` doesn't works because you probably don't have a controller called `Home`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to correct here.

By convention, the initial default controller is called `HomeController`.  ASP .NET MVC uses the name of the controller "Home" to build the routes.  Take a look at a default route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Note that the `defaults` line maps some options to the main route.  Specifically, it provides "default" values for the controller name and action name, and then specifies that the id component is optional.

In this setup, when no controller or action are specified, `Home/Index` would be the default.  So this:

```
http://localhost/
```

Would default to this route:

```
http://localhost/Home/Index
```

But your controller is named `Default1Controller`.  So you'd have to do one of the following:

1. Rename your controller to `HomeController` (or whatever is in your route config); or
2. Update your route config to default to `Default1` instead of `Home`; or
3. Specify the route in your URL: `http://localhost/Default1/Index`

---

Additionally, your `Index` action doesn't look quite right:

```
public string Index()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

I'm not sure the framework is going to know what to do with that string.  Actions need to return `ActionResult` (or any derived class thereof).  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("hello");
}
```

There *may* be some functionality in the framework to automatically wrap a value in a `ContentResult`, I'm not sure.  But at the very least, it semantically seems to make more sense to return an `ActionResult` consistently.  This would also help differentiate between MVC controllers and API controllers.

Besides, even if that `Index` action does work, or even when using a `ContentResult`, all it's returning is a string and not an actual page.  Is that what you want for your default action when a user visits the site?